# Google Workspace Integration Issue Impacting website

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I am encountering an issue with Google Workspace integration that is impacting the functionality of websites. Despite configuring Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) services such as Gmail, Google Drive, and Google Calendar for my domain, I am experiencing persistent difficulties in accessing and utilizing these services seamlessly within my website workflow.

The problem manifests as intermittent synchronization failures between Google Workspace and [Website](https://pets3333.blogspot.com/2024/02/why-pets-hold-special-place-in-our.html), resulting in delays in email delivery, inconsistent file access permissions, and inaccuracies in calendar events synchronization.

**Steps Taken to Resolve the Issue:
**

- Ensured proper domain verification and configuration within Google Workspace Admin Console, including updating DNS records and verifying domain ownership.
- Implemented recommended API configurations and OAuth consent settings to enable seamless integration between Google Workspace APIs and my website.
- Reviewed and updated relevant application settings within Google Workspace Admin Console, such as sharing settings for Google Drive files and calendar event permissions.
- Double-checked user permissions and access controls within both Google Workspace and my website's user management system to ensure consistency and accuracy.
- Monitored system logs and error reports for any indications of failures or misconfigurations, but no specific error messages or warnings have been identified.

Despite these efforts, the integration issues persist, adversely affecting the user experience and productivity of [website](https://pigsnames.com/the-pig-names/) users who rely on Google Workspace services.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Best Regards:
[Ellana & Team](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTR6O2s56q74HgtTZQUqzzPyaV8Y3nbpzKLXQmKUrTfT7rgi7mk0JaRLKLKjh-iouD9FcvM0pjMdDWu/pub)